# differences between x = y and x = y == 1

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

Suppose we have logical image `y` and we want to make a copy of it. What is differences between the following statements:

```
x = y;

x = y==1;
```

Comment: If y is a logical array, both statements return equivalent outputs.

Comment: The second assignment is interpreted as `x = (y==1);`

Answer (score 3):

`x = y` is an assignment. It sets the variable `x` to the value currently contained in variable `y`.

`x==y` is a logical operator asking "Is `x` equal to `y`"?

The statement `x=y==1` sets all parts of `x` to true where the corresponding value of `y` is equal to `1`.

The difference between the two statements you pose is thus that in the first statement, `x=y`, `x` becomes an exact copy of `y`. In the second statement however, `x` becomes a logical matrix with boolean values. `1` where `y` contains a `1` and `0` where `y` contains anything but `1`.

In your specific case, where `y` already is a logical matrix (thus containing only `1` and `0`) both statements are thus equivalent as per the above and then the first statement will be faster as the equality check is redundant and thus adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Your answer is more general, but in the specific question `y` is already a logical matrix, so there won't be any differences in the result. However `x=y` directly assigns the values of y to x without checking whereas `x=y==1` has to check if y equals 1 and then set the corresponding index to 1. So I can imagine the second approach would be slower.